# wait for visual studio GUI in console

Tags: visual-studio-2010, command-line

I'd like to have a little batch script that whenever I close the visual studio GUI automatically runs subversion update, then CMAKE, and then restarts visual studio with the solution. Unfortunately I can't seem to write start the visual studio GUI and wait until it is finished.

I already tried

```
call "%VS100COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat"
start /wait devenv solution.sln
```

Which starts the GUI, but the command line immediately returns without waiting.

I basically would like to have something like

```
call "%VS100COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat"
:START
svn update
cmake 
start /wait devenv solution.sln
GOTO START
```

Is it even possible to wait for the GUI to close?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've run across a little trick that Microsoft uses: [there are two `devenv`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx).

One of them is `devenv.com` and the other one is `devenv.exe`.  `devenv.exe` is the actual Visual Studio IDE that you want to run.

`devenv.com`, on the other hand, is a console-mode program that runs the IDE (`devenv.exe`) and redirects its error messages to `stderr`.  (It's used as part of build scripts, where you want to know what happened when you tried to build.)  Since it starts another program and then returns immediately, it's no good to wait on.

Due to some rules going all the way back to MS-DOS, `.com` files take precedence over `.exe` files, if you don't specify a file extension.

**If you write `start /wait devenv.exe solution.sln` it will do what you want**.

Comment: Ha, I thought I have tried all combinations with start and cmd and devenv.com and devenv.exe - but apparently I did not use this one. Thanks!